# Material design edge-to-edge chips field error display

Tags: material-design

The material design spec for text and chip fields says that errors should be displayed below the field

In the case of edge-to-edge chips fields (like those at the top of the chips page: https://material.io/components/chips/), where should errors be shown? In the example image, space isn't given for the error subscript.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Still below, by overlaying over whatever content is there.